# No entiendo porque no tengo la variable class en mi árbol de decisión

Tags: python

En el código intento gráficar mi árbol de decisión pero tengo problemas con la variable a predecir ya que no se me grafica y aunque intente "forzar" a que use la variable Y como variable a predecir me salta el error y aunque llegue a graficar no tengo la variable class la cual es la que tengo que predecir

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Importo las librerías correspondientes y en busca de soluciones hasta numpy, también importo el dataframe hago el cambio a valores numéricos y aunque la variable a predecir la cambie me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df_tenis = pd.read_csv("tenis.txt",sep =",")

df_tenis
```

Reemplazo los datos de la columna "Cielo" también los hago para las demás exceptuando a la cual quiero predecir la cuál es "Jugar"

```
df_tenis = df_tenis.replace(["Soleado","Cubierto","Lluvioso"],[0,1,2])
```

Especifico cual es mi variable a predecir (la variable Y) y también las variables predictoras (Las variables X)

```
X=df_tenis.iloc[:,0:4]
Y=df_tenis.iloc[:,4:5]
```

Defino con cuanto porcentaje de la data se entrenará el modelo mientras que se predicirá con lo que resta (25%)

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split (X, Y, train_size=0.75)
```

Instancio la variable

```
arbol= DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Entreno el modelo

```
arbol_tenis = arbol.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

El problema viene aquí, cuando gráfico de forma simple no obtengo la predicción que debería de figurar como "class"

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize  = (10,15))
tree.plot_tree(arbol_tenis,filled = True, rounded = True)
#tree.plot_tree(arbol_tenis, feature_names=list(X.columns.values),
               #class_names=list(Y.values), filled=True)
plt.show ()
```

[image: Cuenta con todas las entradas menos la variable a la cual quiero predecir]

Si trato de "forzar" que la variable "class" la tome desde la variable *Y* me salta el siguiente error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 fig = plt.figure(figsize  = (10,10))
      2 #tree.plot_tree(arbol_tenis,filled = True, rounded = True)
----> 3 tree.plot_tree(arbol_tenis, feature_names=list(X.columns.values),class_names=list(Y.values), filled=True)
      4 plt.show ()

'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` para reproducir el problema y el texto del error completo.

Comment: Por consistencia con lo que tienes, ¿no deberías poner: `class_names=list(Y.columns.values)`?

Comment: Tengo el siguiente error ``` IndexError: list index out of range``